# Highchairs Tooltip not showing accurate date time

Tags: datetime, charts, highcharts

I have a written a stats chart using highchairs.com for the daily visits and installs. I want to show the tooltip with Datetime and Names with total values for each series when hover or on click event.

Highcharts tooltip shared Data shared output is displaying with names but not the date and time correctly when you mouseover on the markers.

What I'm doing wrong?

[image: Final output image.]

The code I have written is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/femiva/7yrnreLx/) as well.

```
$(function () {
$('#campaign-container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline',
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day:"%b %e, %Y",
        },
        tickInterval: 2,
        allowDecimals: false,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 3000,
        tickInterval: 1000,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
   },
    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        layout: 'horizontal',
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
                lineWidth: null,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                radius: 5
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Visits',
        color: '#d3d3d3',
        data: [750,850,1000,1250,1050,950,720,850,650,750,950,1050,1150,1250,1450,1650,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]
    }, {
        name: 'Installs',
        color: '#e77378',
        data: [550,650,750,850,950,1050,1150,1250,1150,1050,950,850,750,650,550,450,750,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]
    }]
    });
});
```

Comment: You haven't provided any datetime data for it to work with.  Therefore it is starting 0, which is January 1, 1970 (beginning of epoch time). The fiddle is displaying the date correctly, based on what you've provided it.

Comment: @jlbriggs I have no idea on how to use the current month for the highcharts. If you can edit the jsfiddle or write a code for me that would be good.

Comment: @Maqk, you havent provided any dates in your data, just a set of yValues. Do you know the dates of your data points? If so, include in your `data: []`. Then you can format the date to show as you would like.

Comment: @wergeld I think it should take the current time zone. The data points on yvalues are 2 series of daily visits and installs as you can see but its fetched based on the current month. I tried putting [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 1), 0], but that didn't worked out.

Comment: So if I am on one side of the international date line I would have one value for "today" but if I was on the other side it would be a different value? That is what you mean by "it should take the current time zone"? That is not very useful to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide either:

1) a `pointStart` and `pointInterval` property, on the series level (either in the plotOptions, or in the series object)

2) datetime values in the x values of your data

The datetime values can either by epoch time stamps (in milliseconds), or Date.UTC() objects.

The pointInverval, if used, must be in milliseconds.

Example using the `pointStart` and `pointInterval` properties:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/7yrnreLx/3/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code with the correct date time values and added the customised crosshair.

Here is the final code with a correct data values

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
      tickInterval: 2,
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day:"%e",
      },
      crosshair: {
        color:'#e77378',
        zIndex: 2,
        width: 3,
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 3000,
        tickInterval: 1000,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
   },
    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        layout: 'horizontal',
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2016,0,1),
        pointInterval: 86400000, //1 day
        },
      },
        areaspline: {
                lineWidth: null,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                lineColor:'#e77378',
                fillColor:'#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 3,
                radius: 4,
                symbol:'circle'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Visits',
        color: '#d3d3d3',
        data: [750,850,1000,1250,1050,950,720,850,650,750,950,1050,1150,1250,1450,1650,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]
    }, {
        name: 'Installs',
        color: '#e77378',
        data: [550,650,750,850,950,1050,1150,1250,1150,1050,950,850,750,650,550,450,750,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]
    }]
});
});
```